# Mail Merge using one Word doc but needing many iterations depending on Excel data

Tags: excel, ms-word, mailmerge

This is an updated post from today as the parameters have changed.

I have an Excel sheet with the data.  I have a Word document that instructs me to choose which paragraph to use based on the data in Excel.  For instance, if the NewClient column in Excel has an X, then I choose paragraph 2 for the letter.  If it is blank I choose paragraph 1.  If it has a Y, then I choose paragraph 3.  I have several instances in this document where I have three things to choose from.  Is there a way to do this via mail merge?  I've been reduced to adding columns and filling them with the various paragraphs.  That "works" but it isn't the solution my bosses want. They think that we can somehow use fields and if...then...else to make this Word document magically be produced in each instance.

Comment: Please understand that Stack Overflow is for *programming* questions. Mail merge is, basically, and end-user issue and such questions should be asked on the Super User site. That said, mail merge can probably handle this with an IF field, and field code questions can be on-topic on Stack Overflow. What would be needed, then, from you is the *merge field name* of what you want to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditionally varying text in a mailmerge is a trivial programming task - all done via field coding. For example:

```
{IF{MERGEFIELD NewClient}= "X" "NewClient Text for X"}{IF{MERGEFIELD NewClient}= "Y" "NewClient Text for Y"}{IF{MERGEFIELD NewClient}= "" "NewClient Text for blank"}
```

**Note:** The field brace pairs (i.e. '{ }') for the above example are all created in the document itself, via Ctrl-F9 (Cmd-F9 on a Mac or, if you’re using a laptop, you might need to use Ctrl-Fn-F9); you can't simply type them or copy & paste them from this message. Nor is it practical to add them via any of the standard Word dialogues. The spaces represented in the field constructions are all required. The conditional output can include multiple paragraphs, tables and images, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Why not sort the list in Excel, then make two lists. One with people who have an x and one with people who don't. Then you could do a mail merge in Word for each list.

Comment: Yeah.  That's not what the bosses want.  I could tell you all of the stupidity involved, but you wouldn't believe it.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding where the difficulty is. Its seems like all you would need to do then is create an extra column with the heading Paragraph and copy the formula below down through the names

=IF(B2="x",$J$1,$H$1)

where J1 contains the paragraph you want for the case where there is an x and H1 contains the paragraph for the case there isnt an x. B being the column which contains x or not x

Comment: We have been told we cannot touch the Excel file.  But as the day goes on, it seems that is going to have to happen.  So I thank you kindly for this!!  We may well use it!

Comment: I've just gotten confirmation that we are not allowed to touch the data in the Excel sheet.  We have numerous iterations in our Word document that would mean creating around 25 different documents if we can't figure out a way to use if...then...else in Word.